kubernetes rancher - self singed certificate doesn't let me access the site
I want to use a self-signed certificate for Rancher, but instead of the Firefox error:
Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead

Where I can usually accept the risk and continue, I get this:
Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue
Error Code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER


The weird thing is, if I kubectl port-forward -n cattle-system services/rancher-release 8443:443, everything works fine and I can accept the risk and continue...
How can continue to the website and is there a way to let my computer accept that self-singed certificate?

This fixes it:
Get the rancher-issuer certificate and save it:
kubectl get secrets -n cattle-system tls-rancher -o jsonpath='{.data.tls\.crt}' | base64 -d > rancherCA.crt

Then trust it on your machines that need access to rancher:
sudo trust anchor rancherCA.crt

